# JBoss removes JAR files when deploying EAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I recently migrated from JBoss EAR 6.4.0 to 7.0.0. In my deployments folder, I have a EAR containing numerous JAR files of my project. When I unpack the file after building, all files are there as desired.

**But as soon as I start the server and the EAR file gets unpacked by JBoss, a couple of my project JARs vanish.** The files are simply not there, so my server starts incompletely and my EJB client cannot connect ("*No EJB receiver for handling...*").

Is there any 'smart' mechanism in JBoss that may cause this behaviour?

My colleagues are working on the same project (but different IDE) with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify each jar as a module in the `application.xml` file in the ear context.

```
<display-name>Your-ear-file-display-name</display-name>    
   <module>
      <java>YourEJBJar.jar</java>    
   </module>
   ...
```

Comment: Sure, the modules are all there in `application.xml`. Though, mine are EJB.

Comment: Your EJBs are packaged as `jar` files, right? Are you specifying those EJB jars as 'modules' in the application.xml in META-INF of your ear?

Comment: Yes, the EJBs are packaged as JAR files and are referenced in the application.xml file.